# What is the best way of speccing plugins with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rspec

I'm creating a plugin, and am looking to use RSpec so I can build it using BDD.

Is there a recommended method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I have a solution:

- Generate the plugin via script/generate plugin
- change the Rakefile, and add

`require 'spec/rake/spectask'`

```
desc 'Test the PLUGIN_NAME plugin.'
Spec::Rake::SpecTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.libs << 'lib'
  t.verbose = true
end
```

- Create a spec directory, and begin adding specs in *_spec.rb files, as normal

You can also modify the default task to run spec instead of test, too.

Answer (score 0):

For an example of an existing plugin that uses rspec, check out the  [restful_authentication plugin](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master).  Maybe it will help.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, unfortunately, as restful auth is a generator, the specs are generated in the app that the generator is run against. I'm looking to build the specs within the plugin itself as an alternative to using the regular built-in unit/functional tests.